# Install a plugin on each node in a cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a two-node Elasticsearch 2.2.0 cluster and each node sits on a different physical box.

Now I need to install the Delete By Query plugin. Should I install the plugin on each machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/plugins-delete-by-query.html), you need to install the plugin on each node and then restart your cluster.

> The plugin must be installed on every node in the cluster, and each node must be restarted after installation.

Comment: It's possible to use an automation tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to install plugins on all your nodes in parallel.